# Excel Index Match Countif - trying to count multiple values that match 2 conditions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a formula to count the "ShowEnterConfirmationNumber" instances in column L, but only when the cell below it is blank and there is an instance of 'FALSE' in column H in the row below it.

I've tried Match, index and Countifs but can't seem to find the right combination to return a count of these based on the above conditions.  Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: You should post what formulas have you tried. Also, posting your data example as text instead of as image would help users to replicate your problem.

Comment: Ok, not sure it required a marking down for that, not a huge amount of text.  I haven't posted any formulae that I've used as they have not worked, which is why I am asking for advice on how to go about this.  I can use basic COUNTIFS on both columns, but not sure how to add a condition, potentially with match and index, in order to only count those rows where the row below "ShowEnterConfirmationNumber" is blank and on the same row as the blank in column H the value is "FALSE"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a helper column (e.g. M), add this test in cell M2 and auto-fill down :
`=AND(L1="ShowEnterConfirmationNumber";L2="";H2="FALSE")`
and then count all TRUE (1) values in column M.

And if you want everything in a single cell, without helper column, you can use this :
`=COUNTIFS($L$1:$L$10;"ShowEnterConfirmationNumber";$L$2:$L$11;"";$H$2:$H$11;"FALSE")`
I stopped at row 10, so you have of course to replace this with the row number with the last value in your dataset. Please also be careful for the test on "FALSE"; my syntax works if in your data it is entered as a text string; if it is a real Boolean, you probably have to do remove the "" around the FALSE in the formula.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you so much!

Comment: @kehoewex86 You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: @kehoewex86 Thanks. And just a comment, in case you are wondering why your question was down-voted. I assume this were users that think that your question should have been posted on Superuser, and not on Stackoverflow; I know it says "complex formula development" in the description of what is allowed, so I guess the down-voters didn't consider it "complex" enough ... ;)

Comment: Wow!  I assumed it was just because they got angry that they couldn't answer the question ;) haha